# Are the aliens in "Three Miles Down" the Krolp from Vilcabamba?

Tags: three-miles-down

The asshole aliens from Vilcabamba are of course centauroid in shape, and I vaguely remember them being described as having owl-like heads or faces (or I'm misremembering it). And certainly if they wanted to mess with a 1960s-era Soviet submarine it wouldn't be much of a challenge for them.

Additionally, there is Turtledove's habit of circling back to earlier short stories. I'm about halfway through *Three Miles Down* but also slightly worried that Turtledove won't make it clear one way or the other.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is hard to be definite. I would say that Turtledove gives insufficient evidence for us to be completely sure that the aliens are different, but what evidence there is does tend to point towards this.

A typical Krolp in *[Vilcambamba](https://archive.ph/20130204143041/http://www.tor.com/stories/2010/02/vilcabamba)* is described as:

> a tiger-striped centauroid with a head like a vampire jack-o’-lantern.
> He had sharp, jagged jaw edges — they weren’t exactly teeth, but they
> might as well have been — and enormous eyes that glowed like a cat’s.

The aliens from *[Three Miles Down](https://www.isfdb.org/cgi-bin/title.cgi?3054927)* are also centauroid, but unlike the Krolp,

> they had what looked like feathers, not hair or bare skin. Their heads
> were more like owls than anything else... their eyes were wide and
> yellow

This resemblance of their heads to owls is what leads to their nickname of "centaurowls". There is quite a lot of difference between "a vampire jack o' lantern" and an owl-head, and the centaurowls are not described as being striped. In addition, the Krolp are insanely aggressive, whereas the centaurowls seem much more pacific - entering their ship requires you to think friendly thoughts and say "Friend" (like entering the gate of Moria).

Both races are air-breathing (the centaurowl ship's atmosphere consisted of 82% nitrogen, 17% oxyen), so completely compatible with Earth's atmosphere, and the Krolp breathe Earth's atmosphere with no problems. However, the physical differences between them, and especially the implied difference in mentality, makes me believe that the races are distinct.